# How to add text next to a shape?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add text next to the circle.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <span><div class="circle"></div></span><p>available</p>

   </div>

 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-radius:50px;
font-size:20px;
color:#fff;
line-height:100px;
background: green;
```

}

Right now, the circle is on top `<p>` tag.
I am trying to add two circle: `available` and a red one saying `not available`.  Also, if you know a better way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` takes up 100% of the width by default, which is why your `p` tag wraps to the next line. You can set e.g. `display:inline-block` on the div to change this behaviour.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfo44q7f/2/) for your two circles.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following code :

```
.col-sm-2 > span, .col-sm-2 > p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

What this does is it causes the two elements `span` and paragraph `<p>` tags to become inline-block and hence align on the same line.

See this below :

```css
.circle {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    background: green;
}

.col-sm-2 > span, .col-sm-2 > p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"> <span><div class="circle"></div></span>
        <p>available</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a icon instead. I like the font awesome icon set http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/circle/:

You just add the fontawesome Css files and in your html add:

```
<i class="fa fa-circle">available</i>
```

Comment: Care to explain why?  They are already using the bootstrap framework to layout and style their site, so adding fontawesome to extended the range of available icon is bad practice because?

Comment: Because, you are adding the entire font-awesome library for a single icon that you can make in 4 lines of CSS. Not good practice.

Comment: I know this is not the most efficient solution but it gave me a good idea, so I think it's useful to include under this question.